# How to create 3 subplots with colormapping and real-time plotting in PyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I am currently working on a project in which I have to implement 3 subplots, with a shared y axes, with real-time plotting, into one PyQt window. Now, I found code online for one plot in a Qt window with a clear and redraw method, which suits my needs. Thus, I am trying to modify this code to meet my other specs. Also, I already have code that creates colormaps; albeit, rather janky.

Here is the code that creates one plot in a Qt window that uses the clear and redraw method for real-time plotting

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys
import random
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

    n_data = 50
    self.xdata = list(range(n_data))
    self.ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(n_data)]
    self.update_plot()

    self.show()

    # Setup a timer to trigger the redraw by calling update_plot.
    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer.setInterval(100)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)
    self.timer.start()

def update_plot(self):
    # Drop off the first y element, append a new one.
    self.ydata = self.ydata[1:] + [random.randint(0, 10)]
    self.canvas.axes.cla()  # Clear the canvas.
    self.canvas.axes.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, 'r')
    # Trigger the canvas to update and redraw.
    self.canvas.draw()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Here is my mid-tier code for colormapping

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 15))
chipName = "CHIP"
fig.suptitle(chipName)
axs[0].set_title('I' + u'\u209B' + u'\u2092' + u'\u209C', size=40)
axs[1].set_title('dI' + u'\u209B' + u'\u2092' + u'\u209C' + '/dt', size=40)
axs[2].set_title('Noise', size=40)

# Mock data

x = np.random.random(20000)
y = np.random.random(20000)
colors = x + y

custom_cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    "custom", ["#00008B", "blue", "cyan", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "#8B0000"])

plot1 = axs[0].scatter(x, y, c=colors, cmap=custom_cmap)
plot2 = axs[1].scatter(x, y, c=colors, cmap=custom_cmap)
plot3 = axs[2].scatter(x, y, c=colors, cmap=custom_cmap)    
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(plot1, ax=axs[0], orientation='horizontal')
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(plot2, ax=axs[1], orientation='horizontal')
cbar3 = fig.colorbar(plot3, ax=axs[2], orientation='horizontal')

fig.show()
```

As of now, I am just trying to go through and add subplots. I've tried multiple methods such as replacing

```
fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

with

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 15))
```

or adding

```
self.axes = fig.add_subplot(112)
self.axes = fig.add_subplot(113)
```

With the first method, it creates a matplotlib window, which I'm trying to avoid.
With the second method, it fails to create anything and produces an error.

This is entirely uncharted territory for me. I am just a poor physics major working in my undergraduate lab trying to make stuff work with rudimentary python skills. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you get an error, you should tell us *what* error. Also, be aware that you should normally import Qt *before* any module that might use it (with matplotlib and pyqtgraph being the most important ones).

Comment: The error is num must be 1 <= num <= 1, not 2

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide the full traceback of that error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to create multiple plots in one PyQt window. You can either create more than one canvas or you can divide a single canvas into more than one subplot. It is also possible to do both in the same window! There is starter code for both options below.

Here is an example output of multiple subplots in one canvas.

[image: PyQt Window]

#### Code

Note: I recreated your plots in PyQt, but there are a ton of parameters you can play around with to customize it. This should be a good starting point!

```
import sys
import time
import random

import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # set up the window
        super().__init__()
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._main)

        # create seperate canvas objects
        first_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(9, 6)))
        layout.addWidget(NavigationToolbar(first_canvas, self))
        layout.addWidget(first_canvas)

        second_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(9, 3)))
        layout.addWidget(second_canvas)
        layout.addWidget(NavigationToolbar(second_canvas, self))

        # add subplots to the first canvas
        self._first_axs = first_canvas.figure.subplots(1,3)
        
        # create data and colormap
        x = np.random.random(20000)
        y = np.random.random(20000)
        colors = x + y

        custom_cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
            "custom", ["#00008B", "blue", "cyan", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "#8B0000"])
        
        # access each subplot using regular indexing
        self._first_axs[0].set_title('I' + u'\u209B' + u'\u2092' + u'\u209C', size=40)
        self._first_axs[1].set_title('dI' + u'\u209B' + u'\u2092' + u'\u209C' + '/dt', size=40)
        self._first_axs[2].set_title('Noise', size=40)
        
        # plot data and create colorbars
        self.plot1 = self._first_axs[0].scatter(x, y, c=colors, cmap=custom_cmap)
        self.plot2 = self._first_axs[1].scatter(x, y, c=colors, cmap=custom_cmap)
        self.plot3 = self._first_axs[2].scatter(x, y, c=colors, cmap=custom_cmap)
        
        self.cbar1 = first_canvas.figure.colorbar(self.plot1, ax=self._first_axs[0], orientation='horizontal')
        self.cbar2 = first_canvas.figure.colorbar(self.plot2, ax=self._first_axs[1], orientation='horizontal')
        self.cbar3 = first_canvas.figure.colorbar(self.plot3, ax=self._first_axs[2], orientation='horizontal')
        
        # make the second canvas a dynamic plot
        self._second_ax = second_canvas.figure.subplots()
        t = list(range(50))
        self.yData = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(50)]
        
        # Set up a Line2D.
        self._line, = self._second_ax.plot(t, self.yData)
        self._timer = second_canvas.new_timer(50)
        self._timer.add_callback(self._update_canvas)
        self._timer.start()

    def _update_canvas(self):
        t = list(range(50))
        self.yData = self.yData[1:] + [random.randint(0, 10)]
        # set line data
        self._line.set_data(t, self.yData)
        self._line.figure.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Check for open QApplication.instance()
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if not qapp:
        qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # run it!
    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    app.activateWindow()
    app.raise_()
    qapp.exec()
```